# Random sequential adsorption of rectangles with random aspect ratio

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, stochastic-processes, statistical-physics, packing-and-covering

Jian-Sheng Wang, in his 1994 article *A fast algorithm for random sequential adsorption of discs* ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9402066)), considered deposition only on (small) squares which are not fully covered by the excluded area of discs. Is there any way to implement a similar identification algorithm for rectangles with random aspect ratio? That is, how can one evaluate if such a rectangle can be deposited in a (small) cell surrounded by other rectangles, or if this cell is already blocked and not available for further deposition? Is there any equivalent "excluded area" for such a rectangle?

Comment: I guess you mean https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9402066 ? A slightly different title, I know... Published version is at https://doi.org/10.1142/S0129183194000817

Comment: yes, this one. Sorry, I omitted the last words "of discs"..